# Find last occurance of a Value from a selcted Ms Excel Cells

Tags: excel

I have data like below with delimiter @

Iam@here@for@the@first@time@stop

I would like to Print 'time' by skipping 'stop'.
Any Excel Formula to achieve this ask.

More examples: 
Iam@here@for@the@first@time@stop    -> time 
Iam@here@stop                       -> here 
Iam@here@for@the@stop               -> the 
Iam@here@for@the@first@stop         -> first

Thanks in adv.
Alax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it, you can use

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A20,"@","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")
```

[image]